# Can't get into first gear

Tags: vw, manual-transmission, shifting, golf

My car is a 59 plate ([2009/10](http://www.theaa.com/car-buying/number-plates)) VW Golf. It's been working okay and I just had my MOT done. However, yesterday I went to change into second gear and it ground very badly. Then when I stopped, I tried to put my car into first gear but couldn't at all. I can put it into all other gears including reverse which is under first gear.

I've been able to drive by pulling away in second gear. Just wondering if anyone knew of the issue and could help! Wasn't sure if it might need a new cable or what?

Comment: It would be worth checking the adjustment is correct and also the fluid level before doing anything like removing the box.

Comment: I suggest you edit to say 2009 instead of 59 plate as nobody outside of the UK is going to understand what that means @Callum

Answer (score 1):

Firstly have the clutch checked to make sure its adjusted ok and it not slipping etc. If the clutch is alright you may just have an issue with a slipped gear adjustment rod etc. However if those are ok and the gearbox fluid level is good, there could be an issue with the selector or synchroniser mechanism on first gear. This would require service by a skilled mechanic/gearbox specialist.